# Capistrano 3 doesn't create 'current' directory when I deploy my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my **ruby on rails 4** project into my server with **capistrano 3**, but I get some errors.

First of all, when I do

```
cap production deploy:check
```

everything looks like OK! But when I do

```
cap production deploy
```

I got two errors:

```
DEBUG [e3cf53e3] Running [ -L /var/www/myapp/releases/20131026111326/public/assets ] on mydomain.com
DEBUG [e3cf53e3] Command: [ -L /var/www/myapp/releases/20131026111326/public/assets ]
DEBUG [e3cf53e3] Finished in 0.104 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [304388e5] Running [ -d /var/www/myapp/releases/20131026111326/public/assets ] on mydomain.com
DEBUG [304388e5] Command: [ -d /var/www/myapp/releases/20131026111326/public/assets ]
DEBUG [304388e5] Finished in 0.104 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

The last error I got is:

```
DEBUG [4e4c65ef]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [4e4c65ef]    Unknown database 'myapp_production'
```

So I thought that I should do

```
cap production deploy:migrate
```

But I got a different error: current directory doesn't exist...

I'm very lost. My configuration files are these:

**production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production

role :all, %w{myuser@mydomain.com}

server 'mydomain.com', user: 'myuser', roles: %w{web app db}

  set :ssh_options, {
    keys: %w(/path/mykey.pem),
    forward_agent: true,
    auth_methods: %w(publickey)
  }

fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: :production)

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.0.0-p247'
 set :rake,           "rake" 
 set :rails_env,      "production" 
 set :migrate_env,    "" 
 set :migrate_target, :latest
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'

require 'capistrano/rvm'

require 'capistrano/bundler'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

I'm using capistrano-bundler, capistrano-rvm and capistrano-rails in Gemfile

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capistrano cannot create your database for you, the `current` symlink is never being created because you aren't completing a deploy.

The error you are seeing is because the database does not exist on the database server, it depends exactly on your server (postgresql, mysql, etc) but you'll need to go onto the database server and run something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE myapp;
# Something else, too you'll need to GRANT permissions 
# in the sql server for your production database user, 
# or change the database ownership.
```

Then you should be able to complete a deploy.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to stop `unicorn` before the setup is done. In unicorn script I had mentioned path of `current` directory, I removed those lines from deployment script and added back when setup is done.

Check if your deployment script have such cases.